# Slicing Not NaN values in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, slice, nan

I am python newbie and would appreciate some help!
I have a dataframe called result in the below format:

```
start       end         rf1 rf2 rf3
01-01-2008  10-01-2008  nan 12  nan
02-01-2008  11-01-2008  nan 16  nan
03-01-2008  12-01-2008  32  18  18
```

I want a list of those rfs in each row that are not NaN. Please note that my first two columns are not index. I tried the below code but couldnt get my answer:

```
result_2=result.dropna(axis=1,how='all')
```

Basically I want a list of dates for which the rfs are not NaN.
For ex in the first row my output should give me start date, end date and 'rf2', similarly in last row, my output should give me start date, end date, 'rf1','rf2','rf3'

Comment: Could you tell how the final result should be?

Comment: Do you mean you want to select rows which do not have values of 'rf1' or 'rfr' or 'rf3' as 'nan'? If so then try `result_2=result.dropna(axis=1,how='any')`

Comment: Hello, for each row, I would want the list of columns that are not NaN. For example, in the first row my output would be 'rf2' for the second row my output should be rf2 and for the third row my output should be rf1, rf2, rf3. Basically I am trying to find out the rfs which are not NaN for a combination of start and end date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC you can use [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) having filtered on the `rfX` columns, `groupby` the index and build a list from the resulting groups:

```
df.filter(regex=r'rf\d').stack().groupby(level=0).agg(list)

0                [12.0]
1                [16.0]
2    [32.0, 18.0, 18.0]
dtype: object
```

Or using a list comprehension:

```
[[i for i in row if i==i] for row in df.filter(regex=r'rf\d').values.tolist()]
 [[12.0], [16.0], [32.0, 18.0, 18.0]]
```

or if you need the column names.

```
df['vals'] = df.filter(regex=r'rf\d').stack().reset_index(level=1)\
                                     .groupby(level=0).level_1.agg(list)

print(df)

       start        end   rf1  rf2   rf3             vals
0 2008-01-01 2008-10-01   NaN   12   NaN            [rf2]
1 2008-02-01 2008-11-01   NaN   16   NaN            [rf2]
2 2008-03-01 2008-12-01  32.0   18  18.0  [rf1, rf2, rf3]
```

Comment: `df.filter(regex=r'rf\d')` can be replaced with `df._get_numeric_data()`, don't know if this improves performance or not but commenting as an alternative. And `i==i` might be confusing maybe it's better to use `np.isnan` for readability purposes. Nice answer +1

Comment: Yes agreed that it can be a but confusing, but wanted to avoid the averhead of calling `np.isnan` for scalars @Ch3steR

Comment: Yes, fair point. Maybe `from math import isnan`? Let's leave this to OP, choose what fits the use-case best  :P

Comment: Sounds good to me, `df.filter(regex=r'rf\d').stack().reset_index(level=1).groupby(level=0).level_1.agg(list)` @Datanovice ?

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, you can use `pd.melt` and `join`

```
s = (
    pd.melt(df, id_vars=["start", "end"])
    .dropna()
    .groupby(["start", "end"])["variable"]
    .agg(list)
    .to_frame("vals")
)

df1 = df.set_index(['start','end']).join(s)

print(df1)

                        rf1  rf2   rf3             vals
start      end                                         
2008-01-01 2008-10-01   NaN   12   NaN            [rf2]
2008-02-01 2008-11-01   NaN   16   NaN            [rf2]
2008-03-01 2008-12-01  32.0   18  18.0  [rf1, rf2, rf3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Exclude unrequired columns using the.select_dtypes and find whic remaining meet condition

```
df2=df.select_dtypes(exclude='object').notna()#Excludes the dates
```

Convert the columns to a numpy array

```
t=df2.columns.to_numpy()
```

Generate a series with columns boolean selected as not null and join to df

```
df.join(pd.DataFrame({'listofcols':[t[i] for i in df2.to_numpy()]}))

       start         end   rf1  rf2   rf3       listofcols
0  01-01-2008  10-01-2008   NaN   12   NaN            [rf2]
1  02-01-2008  11-01-2008   NaN   16   NaN            [rf2]
2  03-01-2008  12-01-2008  32.0   18  18.0  [rf1, rf2, rf3]
```

If interested in a general list or all columns that are not null in the dataframe

```
df.notna().any(0).index.tolist()#find any nan on taxis=0 and add to list


 ['start', 'end', 'rf1', 'rf2', 'rf3']
```

Answer (score 0):

one option would be list comprehension:

```
[[x1 for x1 in x if pd.notnull(x1)] for x in df[['rf1', 'rf2', 'rf3']].values]
```